# Uncaught ReferenceError: price_initial_text is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I have a problem. Ill try to explain it.

I have 1 script. It works on 1 site, but it gives error on second one. Same hosting, same CMS..

Take a look.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
$('.product-options input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
        productPrice($(this));
    });
    $('.product-options input[type=radio]').bind('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().children('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).next().addClass('active');
        }
        productPrice($(this));
    });
    function productPrice($option) {
        var regex = /([0-9]+)/;
        var price_initial = 0;
        if ($option.parent().parent().find('.price-initial').size() != 0) {
            price_initial_text = $option.parent().parent().find('.price-initial').text();
            price_initial = regex.exec(price_initial_text)[1];
        }
        var price_additional = 0;
        if ($option.attr('price') != '') {
            price_additional = regex.exec($option.attr('price'))[1];
        }
        $option.parent().parent().find('.price-total').html(price_initial_text.replace(/([0-9]+)/, price_initial*1 + price_additional*1));
    }
});
```

It gives me - Uncaught ReferenceError: price_initial_text is not defined

Ill repeat. That script works on another site within same webhosting.

Im including that custom js after jquery like on working site.

Comment: The error explains pretty well - what does `$option.parent().parent().find('.price-initial')` select? Have you checked to see if it's different between site 1 and site 2?

Comment: Nothing different. Files lays in equal folders, if you mean that.

Comment: You're setting the variable `price_initial_text` in a conditional `if` statement. The error on "site 2" is indicating that variable is `undefined` - which would not happen if the selector `$option.parent().parent().find('.price-initial')` was returning an element. `.size()` is also depreciated. Try using the console to check whether that conditional is block is being reached.